# Double the speed, four times the fuel, yet again

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, rocket-science, propulsion

This question has been asked several times already but it usually involves pushing against the Earth or a rocket carrying the fuel within itself.  Let's simplify the problem to a projectile pushed by a light beam from an external power source.

So a projectile is pushed by a light beam from Earth to achieve velocity $v$.  This brings it at rest wrt a space station already traveling with velocity $v$ wrt Earth.  The space station now pushes the projectile further with the space station's light beam to achieve velocity $v$ wrt space station but $2v$ wrt Earth.

Will the space station use the same amount of fuel to generate its light beam that the Earth used?  Let's also say that the space station originated from Mars so the fuel it carries did not originate from Earth.

Addendum:  Just to be clear, I am not trying to 'debunk' KE.  I want to understand how the logical answer (same amount of fuel at spaceship and Earth) can be reconciled with quadrupling the projectile's KE wrt Earth.  Where is the catch?

The situation at the spaceship is EXACTLY the same as it was at Earth.  Both the Earth and the spaceship see the projectile at rest wrt to them and compute $x$ gallons of fuel to power the light beam to give it a relative velocity $v$.

Comment: Use momentum conservation, Luke!

Comment: Why do you think your addendum objectively clears up the issue of Doppler shifting when the flashing sensor frequency will also be shifted wrt to earth?

Comment: To clarify this problem I would suggest you try working it out yourself.  As it's written it's unanswerable because we have no way of knowing how much fuel the station needs to generate the beam, or how that compares with the energy required by the Earth-bound station producing a beam.  Also space stations normally *orbit* in which case it's velocity will not be in the same direction as the projectile.

Comment: @FlatterMann yes. of course, momentum conservation is a given but I want to know if the station/spaceship will use the same amount of fuel that the Earth did to push it to relative velocity v.

Comment: @Triatticus the projectile will flash the frequency in large digital numbers.  Whether the lettering appears redder or bluer to Earth will not change the numbers themselves.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine logic tells me the spaceship (change from space station) will use the same amount of fuel the Earth did.  The past history or origin of the projectile has no bearing on its mass and how much 'push' will be needed by the light/laser beam to give it a relative velocity v.  Whatever numbers worked on Earth should work on the spaceship.  For all Earth knows, the projectile originated in another solar system and already has a velocity x wrt to its 'real' origin.

Comment: @jay that frequency will not be constant, as it heads away from the station the light hitting it will be shifted, so it will not state the same frequency as when it was at rest wrt the station.

Comment: The work done in Earth's reference frame on the projectile by Earth in the first stage is the same as the work done in the station's frame on the projectile by the station in the second stage, but not the same as the work done in Earth's frame on the projectile by the station in the second stage.

Comment: I think the question is sufficiently clear now, and is distinct from the similar questions. I have voted to reopen. I also deleted the paragraph about Doppler shift. That should not be excluded from answers

Comment: @J.G.  the gallons of fuel used by the Earth and the spaceship are absolute quantities independent of any frame of reference.  They should be same quantity.  If the Earth claims the work done by the spaceship is different from its own, what's so special about the fuel on the spacecraft?

Comment: Neither Earth nor the station expects the two stages to consume equal amounts of fuel because, while they each see the same momentum change, the stages also differ in their starting momentum (though the two reference frames disagree on how they differ: one says they go from $-mv$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $mv$, the other from $0$ to $mv$ and from $mv$ to $2mv$).